# multiple ->select() in doctrine query

Tags: php, mysql, model, doctrine

For a doctrine model, I don't always need to fetch all the columns. I was hoping that I could solve this using

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()->select('a');  
if (!empty($value)){    
    $query->select('b');    
}  
$query->execute();
```

but this does not work...

Does anyone have a clue how this could be done?

Answer (score 10):

Try using `$query->addSelect('b')` instead of `$query->select('b')`.